# VBA Macro - Auto translations of my text in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros, ms-office, translation

I'm currently using Microsoft Document Translator in translating my texts.  Is it possible to auto translate it using VBA Macro?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to solve similar issue and found code somewhere implemented it to suit my needs hope it helps you too.

```
Sub runner()
    Dim conversion As String
    conversion = "hello world"
    MsgBox translate(conversion)
End Sub

Function translate(text As String)
' Tools Refrence Select Microsoft internet Control


    Dim IE As Object, i As Long
    Dim inputstring As String, outputstring As String, text As String, result_data As String, CLEAN_DATA

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

    'choose input language automatic recognition in example
    inputstring = "auto"

    'choose output language czech in example
    outputstring = "cs"

    'open google translate

    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate "http://translate.google.com/#" & inputstring & "/" & outputstring & "/" & text

    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))

    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    CLEAN_DATA = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(IE.Document.getElementById("result_box").innerHTML, "</SPAN>", ""), "<")

    For j = LBound(CLEAN_DATA) To UBound(CLEAN_DATA)
        result_data = result_data & Right(CLEAN_DATA(j), Len(CLEAN_DATA(j)) - InStr(CLEAN_DATA(j), ">"))
    Next


    IE.Quit
    transalte = result_data


End Function
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not Microsoft Translator right?

Comment: How can I define the language I want to be translated? I only get blank message.

Comment: In output string change the value to your country code

Comment: Okay but I'm getting a blank message.  Do you know where the issue is?

Comment: what do you mean by microsoft translator? you mean online webpage? I do not know the code structure for this one. Google translate is somewhat better in translations anyway..

Comment: I'm still getting blank message.

Comment: done not blank anymore

Comment: I edited my answer just copy it and run "runner"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106017/discussion-between-bot-sundi-and-lance).